# Why will choice of coordinates impose functional relations on the metric?

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading Steven Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology*. On page 10 he says:

> In $D$ dimensions there will be $D(D+1)/2$ independent metric
>   functions $g_{ij}$, and our freedom to choose the $D$ coordinates at
>   will allows us to impose $D$ arbitrary functional relations on the
>   $g_{ij}$...

Can anyone tell me why the choice of coordinates will impose functional relations on the metric?

Comment: Does he mean that when you choose specific coordinates do write down (represent) Einstein's equations the solutions for the $g_{ij}$ look different depending on the coordinate system?

Comment: I think that is it. There are basically $D$ degrees of freedom that are NOT fixed by the Einstein's equations. These correspond to our freedom to choose coordinates. Interestingly, this was an essential insight that Einstein himself only achieved after years of worrying about these 'unconstrained' degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have $D$ coordinates, so you get $D$ choices for choosing coordinates -- i.e., I choose eastern standard time, and cylindrical coordinates centered on the sun, measured in kilometers and radians.  This would make the solar system metric go from having ten independent components to six.